# Using format{i} and looping in Python

Tags: python, loops, format

I had to put more than 1900 files on a server.
Now I want to check if all these files are there.

The files have the name like

> XXX0001.txt, and goes until XXX1900.txt

I already did this:

```
import os
var = os.listdir('.')
var.sort()
```

With this, I have all the files in order. But, I still want to check one by one.

How can I do this looping, checking file by file?

Comment: do your files start always at 0001 and have exactly 3 characters before that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check?

Comment: These files have a name: BDS00001. I'm just using these files, I didn't create them.

Comment: I had some problems with connectivity, so I don't know if all the files are on the server. So I just want to check

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filename is always in the format XXX0001.txt and it starts with 0001
You can do something like:

```
for i, filename in enumerate(var):
    if int(filename[3:7]) != i+1:
        print(f"ERROR, file {i} is missing")
        break
else:
    print("All files are there")
```

Comment: Thanks! After a little work, I understood and check everything.